Bevel makes random behavior each time

It seems strange, I made a ring cut (Ctrl+R) of my model, select 3 edges to extrude and do it again by Z axis to add a thickness. After that when I trying to bevel corners, I randomly get this strange result on different corners. Sometimes it happens with right edge, sometimes left, sometimes both.
I have no idea how to inspect the problem, because I saw the normal behavior 20 mins ago and it broke by some reason...


Did you apply the Scale to your object (Ctrl-A > Scale) in Object mode before trying to bevel? You also seem to have some odd geometry on your model so we'll need to see your Blend file.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Sure, this is a new created .blend file where I decided to test it, because I faced this issue in a project file and its behavior keeps the same.

In that case we'll need to see your Blend file as I suggested in my last comment.



I've edited that link into your question which is where I asked you to put it! Links in comments are easily missed and the link includes the icon image which will only display in the question.

The normals on the outer "wings" of your extrusion are inverted as you can see from the red colour after turning on FaceOrientation on the ViewportOverlays.

Use Shift-N with All selected in Edit mode which will turn the whole object blue and try again.

Thanks a bunch, that reason seems not so complex but not obvious))

If you look from below your model you can see that extruding just the edges down has produced a 'shelf' with a front edge but no bottom face. It would have been better to add two edge loops (Ctrl-R) at the right height round the whole model to give the correct thickness then select the 3 faces between the loops and use E > X to extrude them.
